# Calling div from code behind c#

Tags: c#, html

> ```
> <blink>in condition i want to call div from html , which contains background image only, and I      need to call it on just few pages
> ```
>
> with same metadata. So how will i call that div, i tried few ways but
>   nothing helped me.

```
 if (cMeta != null && cMeta.Name == "background")
        {
            if (cMeta.Text == "Yes")
            { 
                Display(Div)
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Set `runat="server"` to `div` markup.

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

Now in code behind you can access the `myDiv`

```
private void DisplayDiv(bool isShow)
{
   myDiv.Visible = isShow;
}
```

Now when you want to show it then just call this function with `true` value

```
DisplayDiv(true);
```

otherwise  just call it with false ,if you don't want to show it.

Comment: could you write down code pls ? And i getting error when i put runat in div markup